# Bash script to check if screen lock is enabled

Tags: bash

I am a novice at shell scripting. I want to store the result of whether screen lock is enabled or not. Here's my script (with something wrong in it):

```
now=$(gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'false')
```

When I `echo`, I get no value stored in the variable `now`.

```
echo $now
```

(gives nothing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your command, you are not reading, you are setting :)

try this:

```
now=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen)
```

I am not sure why are you checking the result of `set`ting the value. Is it a mistake or you intend to do it?

Comment: +1. Also, `now` doesn't seem like a very good name for this parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm planning to write a risk assessment automation software and considering around 50 important security concerns for an organization. So this is one of the concerns. No it was a mistake of checking the result of set